# Set root wrapper to full body height for every component

Tags: javascript, css, components, styled-components

I am working on a React project to create a simple website. I have 10 to 15 components and all of them have different css stylesheets. Now what i want is that no matter what component the user lands on, I want to keep my root wrapper of index.html to be 100vh. But I can't seem to figure out on which style sheet should I add the style for root. If you have any idea, please do share.

Thank You in advance. Keep up the good work

Answer (score 0):

Alike the index.html file in your React project, there might be an App.css file wherein you can set the root's i.e. `body` or `html` `min-height` to 100vh. In App.css, you may include

```
html, body{min-height: 100vh;}
```

Comment: will it be okay if I directly add style tag on the index.html itself.

Comment: yes that should work too adding style="min-height: 100vh;" but only if you are ready to accept this style universally across all modules and components of your website @HimanshuTariyal, but try giving it too body tag